# loop over multiple items in a list? 'Duplicate Value Error'

Tags: apex, method, execute-anonymous, for

I am looping over a list of records and trying to set a field on those records one by one (the field value will be different for each) but my loop keeps putting the same value for each record.

```
List<Id> companies = new List<Id>();
List<Id> PESummaryIds = new List<Id>();
String s;
for(PE_Executive_Summary__c a : [select Id, Company__c from PE_Executive_Summary__c 
                                  where Investor_Id__c = null ]){
    companies.add(a.Company__c);
    PESummaryIds.add(a.Id);
}

for(External_Account_Relationship__c a : [Select Source_System_Identifier__c 
                                             from External_Account_Relationship__c 
                                             where Account__c in :companies]){
    s = a.Source_System_Identifier__c;
}

List<PE_Executive_Summary__c> PESummaries = [Select Id 
                                               from PE_Executive_Summary__c 
                                               where Id in :PESummaryIds];
for(PE_Executive_Summary__c PESummary : PESummaries){
    PESummary.Investor_Id__c = s; // this should be different for each record...
}

update PESummaries;
```

I m doing this in an execute anonymous window too, since its basically a mass one-time update

Comment: Variable `s` is altered in every iteration of your second for loop; hence, by the time you get to the third for loop, it has the last iterated value from loop 2. You need a `Map<Id,String> sourceSysIdentifiersByPESummaryId`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like this:

First, get your summaries and map by company id:

```
Map<Id,PE_Executive_Summary__c> summariesByCompany = new Map<Id,PE_Executive_Summary__c>();
Map<Id,String> identifiersByCompany = new Map<Id,String>();
PE_Executive_Summary__c[] summariesToUpdate = new PE_Executive_Summary__c[]{};

for(PE_Executive_Summary__c s : [SELECT Id, Company__c 
                                 FROM PE_Executive_Summary__c 
                                 WHERE Investor_Id__c = null ]){
  summariesByCompany.put(a.Company__c, s);
}
```

Next, get your identifiers  from the executive summary table and map by company:

```
for(External_Account_Relationship__c ear : [SELECT Source_System_Identifier__c,Account__c 
                                            FROM External_Account_Relationship__c 
                                            WHERE Account__c IN :summariesByCompany.keySet()]){
  identifiersByCompany.put(ear.Account__c,Source_System_Identifier__c);
}
```

Finally, since they are both mapped by company, you can use company Id to tie them together into your final update record (notice 1 less query)

```
for (Id companyId : summariesByCompany.values()){
  summariesToUpdate.add(
    new PE_Executive_Summary__c(Id = summariesByCompany.get(companyId).Id,
                                Investor_Id__c = identifiersByCompany.get(companyId))
  )
}

update summariesToUpdate;
```